# Microphone sound quality is horrible

Tags: audio, input, alsa

**The problem:** Audio output works great, the microphone is recognized by the system but the recorded sound is full of static noise. I have the same problem on Ubuntu (both 19.10 and 20.4), Elementary OS Hera and Linux Mint 19.3, but not on Windows 10.

**What I'm using:** I'm using a packard bell easynote Tj75 notebook, with:

**Audio device:** Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Alsamixer Card: HDA Intel MID
Alsamixer Chip: Realtek ALC272X

**What I've tried so far:** I tried almost everything I could, including:
-all of the suggestions reported here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting
_uninstall and reinstall pulse audio

An interesting thing is what happens if I enable Echo/Noise-Cancellation: 
_it works only on Linux Mint, even if the problem is just resized, not erased
_on Ubuntu and Elementary I cannot access audio settings (from the settings menu): when I click to open the window, it crashes :S

**Any idea?**